# In a gestalt with two different manifesting classes, how do power points work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics, gestalt

As an example, say I were to take psion 7 as one side of a gestalt, and wilder 7 as the other side. Each class grants 46 power points/day, plus each gains bonus power points for high Intelligence and Charisma, respectively.

- How many power points would I gain? Does "Class features that two classes share accrue at the rate of the faster class" apply to power points per day?
- If I gain 46 power points from each class, rather than 46 power points total, could I spend power points from one class on powers from the other class?
- If I gain 46 power points total (and perhaps if I gain 46 power points from each class), how would I determine bonus power points? From the higher of Intelligence and Charisma? From both Intelligence and Charisma?

In all answers, I would like the reasoning behind your answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Talking about RAW here isn’t particularly useful

As an *Unearthed Arcana* variant, the gestalt rules are mostly just suggestions and ideas – fairly fleshed out, for the most part, but it’s a mistake to think of them as really complete rules.

They don’t cover this situation directly. Taken literally, you would simply get the greater number of power points between the two classes, but that is quite dissatisfying; you lose a *ton* of power points compared to the spells slots of a gestalt spellcaster//spellcaster.

The bonus power points for high Int and Cha would combine, though. So the answer there is 46 + ½*ML*(Int+Cha) power points per day.

#### Unfortunately, it is very difficult to identify “best practices”

Simply letting the character combine both power pool counts into one results in a potentially *huge* number of power points, and also provides a flexibility greatly exceeding what spellcasters receive. Thus, 46 + ½*ML*×Int + 46 + ½*ML*×Cha power points per day.

On the other hand, strictly segregating power points for each side of the gestalt is quite out of keeping with how psionics works in general; after all, multiclass manifesters combine all their classes’ power points. But going this route does eliminate most of the balance headaches, simply giving the two sides 46 + ½*ML*×Int power points per day for the psion side and 46 + ½*ML*×Cha power points per day for the wilder side, and the power points cannot be spent to pay for the other class’s powers.

Personally, I prefer the former; it may be a huge number of power points, but then manifesters are a little worse off than spellcasters to begin with, and a gestalt spellcaster//spellcaster isn’t really *that* great an option to begin with. By combining power points, the gestalt manifester//manifester actually synergizes his or her two sides quite well, and the two sides are almost-seamlessly combined into simply *knowing a lot more powers*. That’s pretty solid.

Comment: To be fair, the difference between merging the pools and segregating them is quite negligible.  Taking a secondary manifester class in gestalt for merely the extra power points is probably the singularly worst use of gestalt I can come up with.

Comment: @KRyan I believe that I have come up with a valid counter for your answer. Please review? Please note that I would rather be incorrect in this case. ^^

Comment: @nijineko I don’t see that as a counter at all. I state the same thing in the top half of my answer—and point out that it’s neither useful nor consistent, and isn’t a *good* answer even though it’s the “RAW” one, which itself is an extremely limited concept where an *Unearthed Arcana* variant is concerned.

Comment: @KRyan Thank you for the look-over. As usual, you have excellent analytical abilities.